# $A$ is a countable set if and only if exist a injective function $h: A \to \mathbb{N} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a countable set if and only if exist a injective function $h:  A \to \mathbb{N}  $

I have the second implication: we know that $\mathbb{N}$ is countable then exist a injective function such that $h: A \to \mathbb{N}$  then $A$ is countable. 
But for first implication I don't know what I can do. I try with inverse function but, with my definition of countable set ($A$ is countable set if exist a surjective function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$) and with composition I can't have the correct answer.

Comment: The function $f$ may not be invertible. However you can use it to define an injection from $A$ into $\mathbb{N}$ by mapping each element $a$ in $A$ to some element of the preimage $f^{-1}(\{a\})$. If you wish to avoid using the axiom of choice you can use the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered.

Comment: (1). I can never tell which implication in an iff is supposed to be the first. Please re-word this. I can answer but I dk what part you have difficulty with. (2). Countable means not uncountable . Countable means "finite or countably infinite".

Comment: Counterexample: There is an injective function $h:\emptyset\to\mathbb N$ but $\emptyset$ is not countable by your definition, there is no surjective function $f:\mathbb N\to\emptyset.$

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $A \neq \varnothing$ is countable. So there is $f: \mathbb{N} \to A$ surjective (your definition). To each $a \in A$, $f^{-1}(\{a\}) \neq \varnothing$, let $h(a) = \min f^{-1} (\{a\}) \in \mathbb{N}$  (because $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered). Define $h: A \to \mathbb{N}: a \mapsto h(a)$.

Note, $$(f\circ h)(a) = f(h(a))  = f(\min f^{-1} (\{a\})) = a $$, then $h$ is injective.

Comment: Note, nor $f$ neither $h$ are bijective functions (in general). They are only "inverse" on one side and not on the other .

Answer (score 1):

Thadeu Henrique Costa gave a succinct response, but for educational purposes it seems worthwhile to provide more material and another angle to the method.

The student should study

[Injection iff Left Inverse](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injection_iff_Left_Inverse)

and to round out the course,

[Surjection iff Right Inverse](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Surjection_iff_Right_Inverse).

We can avoid this theory for the OP's question, using, for instructional purposes, a direct approach:

By the [Well ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle), every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element. So there is a function

$\tag 1 \mathcal M: \mathcal{P}^{*}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N}$

mapping any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ to the smallest number of that set.

Exercise 1: Let $J$ and $K$ be two nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Then

$\tag 2 J \cap K = \emptyset \; \Rightarrow \; \mathcal M(J) \ne \mathcal M(K)$

Now we can use the surjective $f$ enumeration to define another function

$\tag 3 \bar {f}^{-1}: A \to \mathcal{P}^{*}(\mathbb{N})$

by

$\tag 4 a \mapsto \{n \in \mathbb{N} \; | \; f(n) = a \} \ne \emptyset$

Exercise 2: Show that $\bar {f}^{-1}$ maps two different elements in $A$ to two  disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. In particular, $\bar {f}^{-1}$ is an injective function.

We know that the composition of two injective functions in an injective function. Now $\mathcal M$ is not an injective function, but by both exercise 1 & 2, it is injective on the image set $\bar {f}^{-1}(A)$ in $\mathcal{P}^{*}(\mathbb{N})$.

The answer to the OP's question is that $\mathcal M \circ \bar {f}^{-1}$ is an injective function from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$. The OP should be able to easily check that this function is exactly the same as the function $h$ defined by Thadeu Henrique Costa.